# Is it possible to use DIffUtil/AsyncListDiffer with other Collection than List?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder, android-diffutils

I'm currently using DiffUtil/AsyncListDiffer with a **List** collection. I'm using the general adapter/recyclerview/ViewHolder implementation. Items are a `List<Uri>`.

Can I use a **LinkedHashSet** instead of a List? Also, if yes, is it a major change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use a LinkedHashSet instead of a List? Also, if yes, is it a
> major change?

No `LinkedHashSet` implements the `Set` interface, not the `List` interface.

Both `Set` and `List` have a common parent `Collection` interface, however `List` is the hardcoded interface type for `DiffUtil` and `AsyncListDiffer`.  You would have to create custom implementations for data structures other than the `List<T>` interface.

Collection/Map cheatsheet :[image]